# Why $N = mg(\cos \theta) - ma_c$ and not only $N = mg(\cos \theta)$ ? (problem with box sliding on sphere)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames

So I've found a solution of my problem online and I don't understand a crucial part of it :

[image]

So, first, why do we consider here the centripetal force as a separate entity from the gravitational force? Indeed, I thought the centripetal force was assumed by the component of the gravitational force that points to the surface: that is to say $ma_c = mg(\cos \theta)$. I also thought the centripetal was equal to the normal force like this:

[image]

So, by this means, $N = ma_c = mg(\cos \theta) \neq mg(\cos \theta) - ma_c$

Comment: welcome but please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Comment: I've added the homework-and-exercises tag. In the future, please use this tag on questions of this type.

Comment: Alright, understood!

Answer (score 1):

There is no centripetal force here. You consider the action of two forces only: one is the gravitational force, pointing downwards vertically. The other is the ball's reaction force N, that prevents the box from 'entering' the sphere. This reaction force represents molecular interactions between the box and the sphere at the atomic scale. In general, you would have two components for this reaction force: one normal component representing constraints on the position of the box, and one tangential component, representing friction forces. The sphere is frictionless, so there is no tangential component. Another implicit assumption is that the box doesn't stick to the sphere. That means that your reaction force N should always point outwards.

This describes the force part. Now on to the motion part. You would like to know at what point your box will 'jump' off the sphere. I.e., at what point it is no longer describing circular motion. One way to get to the solution is to assume that your point is always bound to the sphere (i.e. always describes circular motion), but that there is a point at which for this to happen, you need to add 'stickiness' between the sphere and the box. This is the point where the reaction force N starts to point 'inwards'. This is the point where your box will 'jump'. It's a very common way to solve such 'jump' problems.

I will let you get the rest yourself by projecting your forces onto an adequate axis system. Just note that $a_c$ = $\frac{v^2}{R}$ is the normal acceleration of a point describing circular motion (centripetal acceleration). It's important to distinguish centripetal acceleration from centripetal force. A centripetal force could be, e.g., the gravitation force between the Earth and the Sun, or the tension force in a string attached to a rock which you'd swirl around above your head. The resultant force in your case is 'centripetal' in the sense that it is always directed to the center of the sphere (by adjusting N), but there are no physical, individual forces that are actually centripetal in this case.